# Yii2 Class 'kartik\datetime\DateTimePicker' Not Found on shared hosting server

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, kartik-v

I have installed Kartik datetimepicker in my local directory via composer. Then I uploaded it to my GoDaddy shared hosting server directory but it's showing me that class not found.

I have even tried dosamigos plugin as well for datetimepicker. Same issue with it as well. I followed the same pattern. Installed via composer and uploaded it on server.

Both the plugins are working fine in my local server. But not working on live server.

I am stuck on this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload the complete vendor folder after composer update, not only the module you added. This way you also upload all dependencies.